# Structuring a db to allow multiple products to hit a select component list

Tags: database, database-design

I am designing my first ever database architecture, no real framework to build up on. So I am working on my own! Terrifying.

A huge question I have is for having two separate tables, one being `products`, and one being `components`, and joining them to create a specific part list for a certain build. I'm still messing around with laying out a framework but I need a way for all of tables to communicate, while not having everything together in one place, to make the addition of new products and new components easier.

A thought I had for my architecture is having these two tables:

**Products Table**

```
product_id | product_name | part_list_id
abc123     | product_one  | listb
xyz789     | product_two  | lista
```

**Components Table**

```
part_id | part_name   | part_list_id
62345   | thumb screw | listb
10242   | ziptie      | lista
```

And to get each item would just be a simple

```
SELECT * FROM Components WHERE part_list_id = 'listb'
```

I wish it could be that simple.
The thing that I know of that will make this awful is if a part is both in `lista` and `listb`. Like the addition of `label` below, which just adds unnecessary duplicates.

```
part_id | part_name   | part_list_id
62345   | thumb screw | listb
10242   | ziptie      | lista
14141   | label       | lista
14141   | label       | listb
```

I guess my question would be, is there a better way to have two different items share specific rows from a separate table, without sharing every other row aswell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure so far looks reasonable with a few caveats, so don't be too hard on yourself.

I wouldn't store any information about the components in the Products table directly if possible, so get rid of the part_list_id col. The product_id will give you the hook to build the component list later. This also means that you could add 'temporary' products to the table without needing to commit to a set of components as well.

For the Components table, I would name the cols component_id and component_name, just for consistency (and again, get rid of the part_list_id col as well).

Now, you will need a 3rd table to represent the components that make up a product. You could call this the "ProductComponents" table I guess, and it would have 3 columns at a minimum: productcomponent_id, product_id, and component_id. The productcomponent_id col should be the primary auto-generated key.

Now, if you want to get a listing of the components that are needed for a product, you just search the ProductComponents table by product_id and you can JOIN in the component_name if it helps:

```
select pc.*, c.component_name from ProductComponents pc 
join Components c on pc.component_id = c.component_id
where pc.roduct_id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! I appreciate it. I'm assuming since the products will be made on a manufacturing line there will be testing of each product and stored in my structure. Do you think I should go a similar route with adding a "Tests" Table and a "Tests_Results" Table, combining them like you do above? Just a thought

Comment: Yep, the Tests table would describe the test, and the Test_Results would have a col for the Test id, a col for the Product id being tested, and any other data fields you need.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much for the help.